# Average value of $f(x)=\int_x^1 \cos(t^2) \,dt$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

Find the average value of the function

> $$f(x)=\int_x^1 \cos(t^2) \,dt
> $$

on the interval $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One may recall that if $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then the average value of $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ is defined to be
$$I=\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\,dx.$$
Applying it here gives
$$
\begin{align}
I=\int_0^1 \left(\int_x^1 \cos(t^2) \,dt\right)\,dx&=\left.x\int_x^1 \cos(t^2) \,dt \right|_0^1+\int_0^1 x \cos(x^2)\,dx
\\\\&=0+\int_0^1 x \cos(x^2)\,dx
\end{align}$$ where we have performed an integration by parts, obtaining

> $$
> I=\frac12\int_0^1 \cos(u)\,du=\color{red}{\frac{ \sin 1}2}
> $$

to be the *average value* of $f$ over $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\overline{f} & =\frac 1 {1-0} \int_0^1 \int_x^1\cos (t^2) \; dt \, dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^t\cos(t^2)\;dx\,dt \\[10pt]
& =\int_0^1t\cos(t^2)\,dt = \left[\frac 1 2 \sin(t^2)\right]_0^1 = \frac 1 2 \sin1
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: The average value of an integrable function $f(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$ is $$\frac{\int_a^b f(x)\,dx}{b-a}_.$$

Hint 2: $f(x)$ is closely related to the "Fresnel Integral".